# events should not overlap in month view on fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar to generate a calendar of events - below is a picture of my output.

[image]

Is there a way to make the a new event start at the given time (and NOT take up the whole day/overlap with other events)?  Something like [`slotEventOverlap`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/slotEventOverlap/) but less slot and more just event.

[This answer comes close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9615407/2128691) - and I think I could implement this in my case but it seems overly complex.  Is there an simpler way to do this and I just can't find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version that fix the problem from event that start in the middle of the week and/or less than one a day long

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {

    var currentPosition = $(element).position();
    var currentWidth = $(element).width();
    var pixelsPerDay =  $(element).offsetParent().siblings("table").find(".fc-day-content").width();
    var pixelsPerHour = pixelsPerDay/24;

    //Start Time
    var startTimeOffset = (event.start.getHours() * pixelsPerHour);
    if ($(element).hasClass('fc-event-start')) {
        $(element).css('width', (currentWidth - startTimeOffset) + "px");
        $(element).css('left', (currentPosition.left + startTimeOffset) + "px");
    }

    //End Time
    currentWidth = currentWidth - startTimeOffset; //we have now a new width
    var endTimeOffset = pixelsPerDay - (event.end.getHours() * pixelsPerHour);
    if ($(element).hasClass('fc-event-end')) {
        $(element).css('width', currentWidth - endTimeOffset + "px");
    }

}
```

Comment: this is a lot cleaner than my code, but i've tried it out and there's a problem with end time - the width is not quite long enough.  unfortunately I don't have time to play with it at the moment, but i'll update my answer to show my current code (after a few rewrites).  thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

updated answer:

```
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
      //only show title text once
      if (!$(element).hasClass('fc-event-start')) {
          $(element, 'fc-event-title').text(event.title);
          $(element, 'fc-event-title').css( "text-align","center" );
      };

      var sameDate = (event.start.getDate() === event.end.getDate() &&
                        event.start.getMonth() === event.end.getMonth())
      var pixelsPerDay =  $(element).offsetParent().siblings("table").find(
                                                   ".fc-day-content").width();
      var pixelsPerHour = pixelsPerDay/24
      var currentWidth = $(element).width()
      var currentPosition = $(element).position()
      var endTimeOffest = pixelsPerDay - (event.end.getHours() * pixelsPerHour)
      var endTimeNewWidth = currentWidth - endTimeOffest
      var startTimeOffset = pixelsPerDay - ((24 - event.start.getHours()) * pixelsPerHour)

      //push event bars down a bit so they don't crush the dates
      $(element).css('top', currentPosition.top + 13 + 'px');

      if ($(element).hasClass('fc-event-end')) {
          $(element).css('width', endTimeNewWidth + "px");
      };

      if ($(element).hasClass('fc-event-start') && !sameDate) {
          $(element).css('width', (currentWidth - startTimeOffset) + "px");
          $(element).css('left', (currentPosition.left + startTimeOffset) + "px");    
      };
    },
```

original answer:

I ended up using this code - although it's still a work in progress.

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
    var pixelsPerDay =  $(element).offsetParent().siblings("table").find(".fc-day-content").width();
    var pixelsPerHour = pixelsPerDay/24
    var currentWidth = $(element).width()
    var currentPosition = $(element).position()
    var endTimeOffest = pixelsPerDay - (event.end.getHours() * pixelsPerHour)
    var endTimeNewWidth = currentWidth - endTimeOffest
    var startTimeOffset = pixelsPerDay - ((24 - event.start.getHours()) * pixelsPerHour)
    if ($(element).hasClass('fc-event-end')) {
        $(element).css('width', endTimeNewWidth + "px");
    };
    if ($(element).hasClass('fc-event-start')) {
        $(element).css('width', (currentWidth - startTimeOffset) + "px");
        $(element).css('left', (currentPosition.left + startTimeOffset) + "px");
        $(element).css('top', (currentPosition.top - 44) + "px")
    };
}
```

There are some issues if an event starts in the middle of the week and/or is a less than one day long event - this throws the formatting off, although it can be remedied by commenting out the following line:

```
$(element).css('top', (currentPosition.top - 44) + "px")
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the answer here does not work with the current version of FullCalendar. I created another that does seem to work.

```
            eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                var currentPosition = jQuery(element).position();
                var currentWidth = jQuery(element).width();
                var parent = jQuery(element).offsetParent();
                var siblings = parent.children("table");
                var pixelsPerWeek = siblings.width();
                var pixelsPerDay =  pixelsPerWeek/7;
                var pixelsPerHour = pixelsPerDay/24;

                //Start Time
                var startTimeOffset = (new Date(event.start).getHours() * pixelsPerHour);
                var newWidth = currentWidth;

                if ( jQuery(element).hasClass('fc-start') ) {
                    newWidth -= startTimeOffset;
                    jQuery(element).css('left', startTimeOffset + "px");
                }


                var end = new Date(event.end);
                var endTimeOffset = pixelsPerDay - (end.getHours() * pixelsPerHour);
                if ( jQuery(element).hasClass('fc-end') ) {
                    newWidth -= endTimeOffset;
                }

                jQuery(element).css('width', (newWidth) + "px");
            }
```